# Chapter and section number color in scrbook header

Tags: header-footer, color, koma-script

How can I change the color of the chapter / section numbers in the running title of an `scrbook`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thechapter}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesection}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesubsection}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesubsubsection}\autodot\enskip%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Things}
\section{Important things}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{Other important things}
\lipsum[11-15]
\chapter{Other things}
\lipsum[16-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find how to redefine the headmarks on page 111 of the manual: [https://komascript.de/~mkohm/scrguien.pdf](https://komascript.de/%7Emkohm/scrguien.pdf)

Basically you have to do use the same `\textcolor` commands, just for the `*mark*` commands, as you can see here:

```
\documentclass[headinclude=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thechapter}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesection}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesubsection}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesubsubsection}\autodot\enskip%
}



\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{%
    \chapappifchapterprefix{\ }\textcolor{red}{\thechapter\autodot}\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesection\autodot}\enskip}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionmarkformat}{%
    \textcolor{red}{\thesubsection\autodot}\enskip}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Things}
\section{Important things}
\lipsum[2-10]
\section{Other important things}
\lipsum[11-15]
\chapter{Other things}
\lipsum[16-20]

\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! I was already suspecting that I needed to redefine those; I just couldn't find their default definition so didn't know what to set them to...